# Specify calendars in gnome notification area

Tags: gnome, calendar

I'm synchronizing multiple calendars via the Gnome Online Accounts app.

How can I choose which calendars should display their events in the *Events*-section of the notification area?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not really intuitive, but it seems the calendars used for the notification area can be selected in Evolution calendar. After activating the corresponding calendars, a refresh in the notification area only occurs after browsing in the month back and forth (or vice versa). I don't know yet, if this is reboot proof, but I'd say it's improvable nonetheless. There should be a tool icon to configure the calendars. At least, the GNOME Tweak Tool should offer some way of selecting the calendars to display there.

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, I don't even have Evolution installed on my system, so this is no good solution for everyone I guess... :/ The calendar integration is definitely super strange...